# How to use glm::project to get the coordinates of a point in world space?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have a point (1, 2) in 2D space that I expressed as a vector:

```
glm::vec3 pt = glm::vec3(1, 2, 0)
```

(here I set the third component to 0 - not sure if that's correct?)

I have a model-view matrix to apply a translation to the point:

```
glm::mat4 ModelView = glm::mat4(1.0f);
ModelView = glm::translate(ModelView, glm::vec3(3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f));
```

Now I want to find the actual coordinate of the point in world space. I did some research and `glm::project()` seems to be something that I can use for this. It takes in 4 parameters:

```
detail::tvec3<T> glm::gtc::matrix_transform::project(detail::tvec3<T> const & obj,
                                                     detail::tmat4x4<T> const & model,
                                                     detail::tmat4x4<T> const & proj,
                                                     detail::tvec4<U> const & viewport 
)
```

The first two parameters are the point and the model view matrix which I already have. However what should I use for the 3rd and 4th parameters (the projection matrix and viewport vector)? How can I create/get them?

Answer (score 11):

I think you may be more interested in **glm::unProject**, the inverse of **glm::project**. Long story short, **glm::frustum**, **glm::perspective** and **glm::perspectiveFov** are good candidates for building the **proj** matrix, while something along the lines of `vec4(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)` should be a valid **viewport** vector. It really depends on how you set up your OpenGL camera.

A full example should help.

## To screen space and back

Import required libraries:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/vec3.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace glm;
```

Our main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
```

This is the original point, in so-called object space. If you were loading a mesh from a file, you would find these XYZ coordinates in the file.

```c
    vec3 original(1.0f, -2.0f, 3.0f);
```

The **model** matrix specifies where the object is positioned in the scene. The **view** matrix specifies the relative position of the positioned object with respect to the camera. In OpenGL these matrices are often combined in a single matrix called **modelview**. I opted for the term **model** here, because is what GLM documentation uses, but your term *modelview* is more appropriate for this case, I believe:

```c
    mat4 model = translate(mat4(1.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f));
```

The **projection** matrix represents the lenses and aperture of a camera, and is what actually deforms the scene in a way that it simulates perspective, making objects that are far away smaller. You can use a GLM function such as **frustum** that behaves like the GL counterpart **glFrustum**:

```c
    mat4 projection = frustum(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
```

The viewport specifies the size and position of your drawing area. For a 640x360 window you would typically use something like this:

```c
    vec4 viewport(0.0f, 0.0f, 640.0f, 360.0f);
```

The **project** function does the magic of projecting the original point to the screen:

```c
    vec3 projected = glm::project(original, model, projection, viewport);
```

The **unProject** function does the opposite:

```c
    vec3 unprojected = glm::unProject(projected, model, projection, viewport);
```

You can now see that these two functions are one the inverse of the other:

```c
    cout << original.x << " " << original.y << " " << original.z << endl;
    cout << projected.x << " " << projected.y << " " << projected.z << endl;
    cout << unprojected.x << " " << unprojected.y << " " << unprojected.z << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Mathematically, this is what is happening behind the scenes: a point **original** in **object space** is projected to **screen space** by multiplying it by four matrices model, view, projection and the viewport matrix:

```c
projected = Viewport * Projection * View * Model * original
```

While the opposite transformation, which is what you are looking for, is essentially:

```c
unprojected = (Viewport * Projection * View * Model)^-1 * projected
```

## Full code

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/vec3.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace glm;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vec3 original(1.0f, -2.0f, 3.0f);
    
    mat4 model = translate(mat4(1.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f));
    mat4 projection = frustum(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
    vec4 viewport(0.0f, 0.0f, 640.0f, 360.0f);

    vec3 projected = glm::project(original, model, projection, viewport);
    vec3 unprojected = glm::unProject(projected, model, projection, viewport);

    cout << original.x << " " << original.y << " " << original.z << endl;
    cout << projected.x << " " << projected.y << " " << projected.z << endl;
    cout << unprojected.x << " " << unprojected.y << " " << unprojected.z << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if I dont know the position of the vertex. Instead I just wanted to get the coordinates of any pixel that I click on the screen?

Comment: The algorithm above is a proof of concept that shows projection and unprojection. In your case you don't have `original`, which means that you have to construct `projected` based on user input. If the user clicks in `(x, y)` you could declare `vec3 projected(x, y, someZ)`. How you set `someZ` is  dependent on what you want to do exactly. You could set it to `0` if you are just interested in getting any point along the projection line; or you could set it to the depth of the rendered pixel if you want to reconstruct the actual 3D position of the *surface* point that was clicked.